# AWS Body mapping template get current date time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to get current date time in AWS Body mapping template as below:

```
{
    "requestedTime": "$util.time.nowEpochMilliSeconds()"
}
```

But the value is "" for the above. Tried $context.requestTime as well, but didnt help.

Is there any way to get the current date time requested.

Regards

Comment: What is AWS Body? What is the `$util` and `$context` you mention?

Comment: not sure why are you using util to access current time. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference . Did you try both $context.requestTimeEpoch && $context.requestTime ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about the mapping template of the Integration Request block of AWS API Gateway.

`$context.requestTime` and `$context.requestTimeEpoch` don't work in the test environment.

So you first need to deploy your API and then if your curl your endpoint, it should work.